# function works on Unity, not on Phone

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, android-emulator

I'm pretty new to creating mobile games on unity, so I've recently encountered an issue.
My inventory takes an item (first aid to heal the player) and when the game is run on unity, i press the item on the Device Simulator Device Package and it works (Debug.Log shows it being used on the console). I build and run onto my emulator (LD Player) but the item function doesn't work. It shows that the button is being pressed , but for some reason the function isn't being run.

```
    public void UseItem()
    {
        //Use the healing pack
        if(item != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Healing has occured!");
            //Heal the player by a certain amount, then delete item.
            item.Heal(healAmount, player);
            item.RemoveFromInventory();
        }
    }
```

The player has a Heal() function which increases the player's current health by an amount and modifies the health bar accordingly.

```
    public void RemoveFromInventory()
    {
        //remove the item from the inventory.
        Inventory.instance.Remove(this);
    }
```

```
public void Remove(Item item)
{
    //Remove the item from the list.
    items.Remove(item); 
    if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
    {
        onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Update:
I ran the logcat through Android Studio and the error i got was

```
2021-04-05 12:19:35.119 3615-3634/? I/Unity: Healing has occured!
    UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
    InventorySlot:UseItem()
    UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction:Invoke()
    UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
    UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
2021-04-05 12:19:35.123 3615-3634/? E/Unity: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
      at Item.Heal (System.Int32 amount, PlayerBehavior currentPlayer) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
      at InventorySlot.UseItem () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
      at UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
      at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
      at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1].Invoke (T1 handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
      at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
      at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchPress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData
```

Which is weird, because i set up my Start() function to search for game object with tag "Player" and then grab the script from said player.

Final Update:
I changed my Heal() function so that whenever it gets called, I do a search for the player and now it works fine.

```
public virtual void Heal(int amount, PlayerBehavior currentPlayer)
    {
        currentPlayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerBehavior>();
        //increase the player health by the amount the pack gives.
        currentPlayer.HealDamage(amount);
    }
```

Comment: I would [debug your emulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDsqTooAIZQ&ab_channel=HowtoIssue). From the code you have provided nothing appears to be wrong. Once you setup Android Studio with the emulator, use logcat to see debug print outs.

Comment: got an "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object." error when I debugged it

Comment: If you are getting that error after the printout of Healing has occurred I would think it is throwing due to the item.Remove(item). It is the only place you are not doing error checking of obj !=null. The other possibility is if your item.Remove is removing the item from the list, deleting it and your callback onItemChangedCallback is internally in the item you are deleting, it can't run the callback function if the object is destroyed.

Comment: turns out, my Heal() function wasn't able to find the player, so I added 

currentPlayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerBehavior>();

inside of the function and now it works fine. Cheers.

Comment: Gotcha. I would recommend saving the reference of the player either by making it a serialized field or grabbing that reference in the Start() function. Continually grabbing the reference at runtime can get expensive depending on how often the Heal() is called.